# Getting AD groups recgnized in sudoers file

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory

I am using winbind and samba to authenticate Ubuntu 12.04+ machines against Active Directory. I followed this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADAuthentication

Everything worked just as expected. I am able to register the machines on AD, I can ssh into them using my Windows credentials, I can add user to the sudoers file and permissions work fine. The issue I am having is when I add a AD group to sudoers, nobody in that group has privileges. Also, if I getent a user, again everything comes out fine form AD. If I getent group , it returns nothing. Not sure where I am disconnected. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please post the relevant line(s) from your `/etc/sudoers` file

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it was a typo in nsswitch.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a typo in nsswitch.conf that prevented groups from being read.